# Pandas update index after dropna for a multi-index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

we are working with MultiIndex DataFrames. If we drop some lines (after either slicing lines or dropna), index is not updated.
If define a df that has one na.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1],[1]]))
df.loc[(0,1),1] = 1
df.loc[(0,1),0] = 1
df.loc[(1,1),1] = 1
```

After dropna, index still has (1,1) in Index though df has not.
`df.dropna().index` returns `MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], [1]], labels=[[0], [0]])`

`df.dropna().reindex().index` returns `MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], [1]], labels=[[0], [0]])` as well

What is best way to do that?

I use Python 3.5 and pandas 0.19.2.

Thanks!!

Thierry

Comment: (1, 1) is not in the index after dropna:

    `(1,1) in df.index` returns `True`

    while `(1,1) in df.dropna().index` returns `False`

Is your problem that `df.dropna().index.levels[0]` returns `[0,1]` instead of just `[0]`?  If so, how do you index to use index.levels?

Comment: what is exactly the problem with the index after `dropna()`? If i do: `x = df.dropna(); x.index.get_level_values(0); x.index.get_level_values(1)` - everything looks good